# Necessary and sufficient condition for line of curvature to be parametric curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

**Necessary and sufficient condition for line of curvature to be parametric curve is F=0, M=0 and EN−GL≠0**

Let the line of curvature b parametric curve such that u= constant and v=constant.

So combined the differential equation of parameter curve is
dudv=0.

Now differential equation of line of curvature is
(EM-FL)du$^2$+(EN-GL)dudv+((FN-GM)dv$^2$ = 0

So from above equations
EM-FL=0,FN-GM=0 and EN−GL≠0.

But as per my understanding since parametric curve has one parameter so other is constant so u=constant or v=constant or in another form  parametric curve is r(u,c) or r(c,v) where c is constant.

Hence either du=0 or dv=0.
So either EM-FL=0 or FN-GM=0.
Further,
Since dvdu=0 hence EN−GL≠0 .

Could you explain why book has both parameter of parametric curve u=constant and v=constant and why both term taken EM-FL and FN-GM of du$^2$ and dv$^2$ equal to 0.

Comment: You should actually learn to use MathJax if you're going to contribute to and post on this site. Then you can write actual mathematics so that it is legible for all of us. Then you write $EN-GL\ne 0$. I think you are misinterpreting whatever book you're reading. It's clearly classical and "old-fashioned" in today's world. At any rate, the conditions $F=M=0$ tell you that *both* parameter curves are lines of curvature, not that one is. And the inequality tells you that *only* those are lines of curvature, i.e., that the point is not an umbilic point.

Comment: Ok understood. But why both term taken EM-FL and FN-GM of du2
 and dv2 are taken equal to 0. Where as in case u=constant then du=0 so it should be EM-FL ≠0 similarly when v=u=constant then dv=0 so it should be EN-GM ≠0